# Jquery/PunBB Replace Number with String

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, replace, punbb

Using PunBB on Forumotion the idea was to use the Points system to replace the number of points displayed with a string of text. Using a span class I first defined a class 'honorpoints' around the code that shows the number of points a user has.

```
<span class="honorpoints"><!-- BEGIN profile_field -->{postrow.displayed.profile_field.CONTENT}<!-- END profile_field --></span>
```

When using that code on the forums it will display a number, based on a user's points, next to their username. The following jQuery code was what I tried to use to replace the number.

```
$(".honorpoints").each(function(){
    var elm = $(this);
    var number = parseFloat(elm.text(), 10);
    if (number >= 1 && number <= 500) {
        state = "rank 1";
    } else if (number >= 500 && number < 3000) {
        state = "rank 2";
    }
    elm.text(state);
});
```

However, this doesn't do anything and the numbers are still there. It's supposed to replace UserA : 234 and UserB : 571 with UserA : rank 1 and UserB : rank 2. The code does work however when used on jsFiddle and when working with solely numbers instead of the {postrow.displayed.profile_field.CONTENT} code.
Help is appreciated!

Comment: Can we see what `{postrow.displayed.profile_field.CONTENT}` outputs?  What does a `console.log('"'+elm.text()+'"');` placed right after the `var elm = $(this);` declaration produce (F12, Console tab to see console output for Firebug or Developer Tools on FF or Chrome)?

Comment: @ZachShipley Imputing the console.log code there didn't seem to do anything when inspecting the element in Chrome. Here's a link to part of the forum, to the right of the poster's name is a number along with their rank. The number is in the span class of 'honorpoints' yet the code doesn't seem to even affect it. http://www.bvgstudios.net/t141-community-keep-communicating-7-10-2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the source of the page you provided in your comment, I believe your `$('.honorpoints').each` method is being called before the document is fully loaded (99546.js).  Unless I'm missing something, you need to wrap that method in a `$(document).ready` function so it's executed only once the DOM is ready:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".honorpoints").each(function(){
        var elm = $(this);
        var number = parseFloat(elm.text(), 10);
        var state = "";
        if (number >= 1 && number <= 500) {
            state = "rank 1";
        } else if (number >= 500 && number < 3000) {
            state = "rank 2";
        }
        elm.text(state);
    });
});
```

I also added a declaration for the `state` variable since it's a good practice (as it currently is in your question, the `state` variable is actually `window.state` because it was not previously declared).

Answer (score 0):

The following line try to parse `"UserA : 234"`, that's why you're getting error. `parseFloat(elm.text(), 10);`

You have to fix your `if`s, both match `500`

You can fix it using the following code:

```
$(".honorpoints").each(function(){
    $(this).text(function(i, text) {
        return text.replace(/\d+$/, function(match) {
            if(match >= 1 && match <= 500) return "rank 1";
            else if(match > 500 && match < 3000) return "rank 2";
        });
    });
});
```

Explanation:

`$`: matches end of string;
`\d`: matches only digits;
`+`: matches the match one or more times, so it can match `0` and `5000000`;
[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fFR6d/1/)

*References*:

- `Regexp`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp
- `replace`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace
- `.text()`: http://api.jquery.com/text/

Comment: @user1567186 Did you put it in `$(document).ready` ? You can see that my demo is working.